# MySQL CREATE TRIGGER using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have read some other posts like mine, but none of them solve my problem,
I have two tables, user and purchase, When a user signup, I want to add the same user_id to the purchase table as well. I try to right a php code for that like this:

```
$query = "CREATE TRIGGER `purchase_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO purchase (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id)";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if($result){echo "<br>TRIGGER Success!";} else {die("<br>Database query failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));}
```

this is the error I get:

```
Database query failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I'm sorry if the question is repetitious.

Comment: 'purchase_insert' should be inside the backtick

Comment: 'purchase_insert' should be `\`purchase_insert\`` and also the `\`user\`` ...should have an `END` statement

Answer (score 0):

It should be back tick not single quotes

```
CREATE TRIGGER `purchase_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO purchase (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id)
```

**UPDATE**

Try this

```
DELIMITER$$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `purchase_insert` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `user`
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO purchase (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `END` not needed?

Comment: I copied the exact same code , now the error changes to `Database query failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: @coolester man : See my updated answer!

Comment: @Tamil you mean I put All of that in the query variable and run it? It gave an error, again. but thank you.